# GCC (MinGW) игнорирует атрибут «packed»

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, выравнивание

У меня есть код:

```
#define PACKED __attribute__((packed))

struct PACKED TgaHeader {
    uint8_t  id_length;
    uint8_t  color_map_type;
    uint8_t  image_type;

    /* Color Map Specification (5 bytes) */
    uint16_t first_entry_index;
    uint16_t color_map_length;
    uint8_t  color_map_entry_size;

    /* Image Specification (10 bytes) */
    uint16_t x_origin;
    uint16_t y_origin;
    uint16_t width;
    uint16_t height;
    uint8_t  pixel_depth;
    uint8_t  image_descriptor;
};

typedef struct TgaHeader TgaHeader;
```

Если сложить размеры каждого поля структуры в отдельности, то должно получится 18, но:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(TgaHeader)); /* —→ 20 */
```

Компилятор: `gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)`.
Компилирую так: `gcc si.c -o si.exe -lgdi32 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -pedantic`.

Comment: Похоже, системозависимо. 6.3.0 на 64-битном дебиане даёт 18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Некоторый гуглёж показал, что это [подтверждённая бага в minGW](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52991), тянувшаяся с 12-го года и вроде как устранённая в восьмой версии компилятора. Рекомендуемый обход — использование при компиляции флага `-mno-ms-bitfields`